# PyAutoGui while loop interruption

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, pyautogui

So I have been searching the Internet trying to figure out what I am doing wrong here. Basically, I want to create a script that will prompt the user to enter a number, then perform the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> paste operation that many times. I have tried variation upon variation of the below, but it is just not working.

The commands work fine outside the loop, but the moment I try to loop it, the program just crashes. I am probably missing something obvious, but I have been trying to find that something for the last 2 hours without any luck. Any help is appreciated.

```
import time
import pyautogui

x = input()

time.sleep(5) #delays the next process by 5 seconds

def work():
    global x
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','v')
    time.sleep(.25)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    time.sleep(.25)
    x = x - 1

try:    
    while x > 0:
        work()
    else:
        pass

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

OK i figured this out. x > 0 was the problem. As the code stands now x is a string and you can't compare a string to an integer.

So what i did was add this after the user input

```
x = int(x)
```

Now it works perfectly. If i had run the program from the command window i would have found this problem hours ago. I will know better for next time.